# DELL R320 High Temp/Throttling

Tags: dell

I cannot find the info I'm looking for on the Dell site after a brief look. I'm investigating a sluggish server and have discovered the following during the time the alerts were raised in the log of a Dell R320:

```
The system inlet temperature is greater than the upper critical threshold.
```

Would the server have throttled the CPU due to this for protection? Or not?

I cannot seem to find info on that.

Certainly the timings correspond to the unresponsiveness of the server in question.

Thanks.

Comment: Better have a look if the fans are working OK.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Fans are fine, the DC has an aircon issue. My question is around whether or not this could cause the server to start throttling CPU or not? I can't find that info in documentation. Thank you.

Comment: Neither did I, hardly a word about cpu temperature,apart from setting the parameters.  Perhaps their manuals are not as good as their products used to be?   Did you ask Dell themselves?

Comment: 1. What is the inlet temperature reported?
2. Do you see any thermal trip event. 3. What is the temperature reported for CPU sensors?
It is possible to throttle CPU if the temperature inside the box is too high. In your case, the inlet itself seems to be high.